# hypercube largest number of neighbours with value 1

Tags: probability, statistics

I have the following question regarding a statistical property of a hypercube. This hypercube is defined to have the dimension L. Each vertex of the hypercube has either value 1 with prob. p or value 0 with prob. 1-p. 
Now I am interested in the expectation value N of vertex-neighbours of value 1, that a random vertex with value 1 has. This is of course just N=p*L, since each vertex has L vertex neighbours. Now the tricky question is, at least for me, what is the expectation value for the largest N on a hypercube of size L and prob. p. Hope you can help and thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand the question at all, check if you wrote what you meant or you misspelled something. I suppose you meant "average number of **neighbor** vertices with value 1". But the question itself is what I don't understand, "largest on average"???

Comment: I edited my question. Is it clear now?

Comment: If $L=1$ then the expectation seems to be  $2p-p^2$.  If $L=2$ then it seems to be $4p-4p^2+4p^3-2p^4$.  would expect it to be a $2^L$th degree polynomial in $p$

Comment: Hallo Henry, how did you get those numbers?